# nginx on Fedora 30 setup

Tags: fedora, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am installing nginx on Fedora 30 following a tutorial (I don't know the rules whether I can or not publish a tutorial link here).

The tutorial mentions that I should access to this IP address `192.168.0.3` in order to show the test page, but for me it shows nothing.

These are the steps done (If you need any clarification or details don't hesitate).

```
[root@localhost sites-available]# mkdir /var/www/wisdompetmed.local/

root@localhost sites-available]# echo "Site coming soon" > /var/www/wisdompetmed.local/index.html
```

[image: nx]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that machine's IP 192.168.0.3?

Comment: Welcome! Why not just `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`? What explanation does the tutorial give for using that ip?

Comment: No explanations it has done , he just mention it as default ip in ubuntu

Comment: I can share link of the tutorial for more explanation?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyzoN.png

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyzoN.png  
This is the image shown when visiting 127.0.0.1 or localhost but that is not the text that I have written

Comment: @AhmedC For testing a web server in the machine it's installed you need to go to localhost or `127.0.0.1`. `192.168.x.x` is a [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), generally your home's. These kind of ips is provided by your router/modem. It can be any ip, for example you can test what is your private ip with this command: `hostname -I`. It is useful to comunicate with other devices in the same network. If you are not accessing from another machine than the server just use `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @guillermochamorro

Comment: I have tested your command hostname -I and it provides me three IP adresses  ; that outputs the same  result as localhost (same webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing a web server in the machine it's installed you need to go to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

The ips `192.168.x.x` are part of a [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), generally your home's. These kind of ips are provided by your router/modem. It can be any ip, for example you can test what is your private ip with this command:

```
hostname -I
```

This ip is useful to comunicate with other devices in the same network, but if you are not accessing the server from another machine just use `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`.

---

You have two web servers, fedoras' apache (the service is called `httpd`) and nginx. You have to use one or the other, not both. If you want to use nginx, you have to disable apache.

These would be the commands to achieve this:

```
# stop apache
sudo systemctl stop httpd

# disable it
sudo systemctl disable httpd

# start nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx

# enable it
sudo systemctl enable nginx
```

---

Edit the file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, look to the keyword `root` and change it to look like this:

```
root /var/www/html;
```

Restart the server:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Add the user `www-data`:

```
sudo useradd www-data
```

Change the owner of `/var/www/html`:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

Change the permissions of `/var/www/html`:

```
sudo chown 755 /var/www/html
```

Create the file `/var/www/html/index.html` with the content:

```
<h1>My awesome site</h1>
```

If everything is ok, go to `http://localhost` and you should see this:

## My awesome site

Comment: Thanks for your full answer but is it necessery that It shows the same page or not ? because my page is like in the link above ( I edited my post below to add the image)

Comment: That means that the webserver is still running. What does the command `sudo systemctl status apache2` return?

Comment: Apparently the service in fedora is called `httpd` not `apache2`. I updated the answer, with the commands.

Comment: For apache2 , you are right . there is no service apache2 ; runnig this command
"sudo systemctl status apache2 " shows me 
Unit apache2.service could not be found.
Instead when I type sudo systemctl httpd that shows me ->  httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled;>
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d

Comment: I think that Fedora 30 differs in nginx Setup than Ubuntu Setup that I am following btw

Comment: @AhmedC, I got it, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and for keeping answering ! Thanks very much

Comment: @AhmedC I updated the answer, now should work.

Comment: Yes I have tested it and it works so we consider the folder of /var/www/html as the main folder of the website but why we have added the new user?

Comment: Glad to hear it works ️. [Here is an explanation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873839/what-is-the-www-data-user)

Comment: Wow thanks @guillermo , I was there (at the link of the explanation)